# Tree grid ajax does not refresh in extjs

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have been working on a project where i have used extjs to display some service plans. i am able to populate it in the beginning. then i want a button onclick of which new data is to be populated in the grid.
I am able to make a successful call to the function in my tree service but the data is not displayed.
my treegrid button code is:

```
{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Search',
                listeners: {
                    click: function () {
                      //  Ext.getCmp('tree').getView().refresh();
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            method: 'GET',
                            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                            fields: ['planid', 'id', 'text', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'iconCls', 'expanded', 'leaf'],
                            params: {
                                serviceplanid: serviceplanid,
                                userid: userid,
                                // startdate: startdate,
                                // stopdate: stopdate,
                                initialstate: initialstate,
                                fonttype: fonttype,
                                fonttypeex: fonttypeex
                            },
                            url : '/BloomMatrix2/TreeService2.svc/getfulldata',
        reader: new Ext.ux.aspNetJsonReader({ root: 'children'
        }),

        success: function (response) {
                                //console.log(response);
                                //swapStrore();
                            }
                        });
                    }                       
                }
            },
```

and my service reads functions:

```
[WebGet()]
[OperationContract]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public string getdata(String serviceplanid,String userid, String initialstate,String fonttype, String fonttypeex)
 {

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN GETDATA"+initialstate);
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetConnectionString("YourConnection"));
    Conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[VMResults_GetCategoriesTree]", Conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServicePlanCurrent", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "N";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds1);
    String ret=makeJSON(ds1,initialstate,fonttype,fonttypeex);
    return ret;
}

[WebGet()]
[OperationContract]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getfulldata(String serviceplanid, String userid, String initialstate, String fonttype, String fonttypeex)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN GETDATA" + initialstate);
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetConnectionString("YourConnection"));
    Conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[VMResults_GetCategoriesTree]", Conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServicePlanCurrent", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "Y";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    String ret = makeJSON(ds, initialstate, fonttype, fonttypeex);
    return ret;
}
```

i have to call the latter one onclick of the button..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a store definition on the tree with the proxy that talks to the server. See Sencha examples.

Alternatively if you want to run your own AJAX request as you have in your code than you need to create [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) objects out of the manually parsed data in your success block and add them one by one to the tree panel - not going to be pretty.

Comment: nothing happens while i tried the above method that is trying store defination on the tree with proxy to talk the server.
in this case am able to call the function but when it writes a json string an error occurs. Basically the parameters are not being read there
need help urgent.

Comment: However the second method is way too confusing..cant i just refresh the grid after the function fetches the json and get the service plans displayed

Comment: best thing to do is to follow examples closely. if you run into an error ask for help to solve that specific problem.

Comment: I guess i am able to fetch data but the tree grid is not being refreshed. Any idea where should i put this loader call:
tree.getLoader().load(tree.getRootNode()); 
thankx for constant replies.

Comment: loader? what version are you using?

Comment: i know i am close,its just that data JSON has fetch from the server is not being displayed on the tree grid.
need help urgent